# Odoo from old apie to new api and error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python-2.7, orm, full-text-search, odoo, odoo-9

I was trying to use functions from old api to new api:

```
@api.multi
def search(self, *args, **kwargs):
    offset = kwargs.get("offset", 0)
    limit = kwargs.get("limit", None)
    order = kwargs.get("order", 'complete_name')
    context = kwargs.get("context", None)
    count = kwargs.get("count", False)
    for index, expr in enumerate(args):
        if expr[1] in ['like', 'ilike', 'not ilike', 'not like', '=like']:
            args[index][2] = re.sub(r"\s+", '%', expr[2])
    return super(stock_location, self).search(*args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
def name_search(self, cr, uid, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=80):
    args.append(['complete_name', operator, name])
    ids = self.search(cr, uid, args, limit=limit, context=context)
    return self.name_get(cr, uid, ids)
```

I got error.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 680, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 509, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 892, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 884, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 381, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 6053, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5910, in _onchange_eval
    method_res = method(self)
  File "/home/del/addons/mik_stock/wizard/stock_operation.py", line 193, in onchange_picking_type
    if self.env['stock.location'].search_count(domain_from) == 1:
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 490, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1634, in search_count
    res = self.search(cr, user, args, context=context, count=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 380, in old_api
    recs = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5361, in browse
    return self._browse(Environment(cr, uid, context or {}), ids)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5354, in _browse
    env.prefetch[cls._name].update(ids)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

When I use only `search` function with decorator `@api.multi` everything seems ok. So maybe this error because of `name_search` function? Do I have decorate this function and `cr, uid, ids` change to `self.env`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your domain (search conditions) properly.

Your **args** should contain List of tuples,
like

- **[('phone','=','1122445566'),('id','!=',self.id)]**

In short,

- **[(field, operator, value)]**

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't do that becauce I'm doing counting:  if len(location_from_ids) > 0:
     domain_from.append(('location_id','in',location_from_ids))
        if self.env['stock.location'].search_count(domain_from) == 1:

Comment: I am talking about **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'** error at the end of your error log.
You are getting this error because of 
>>args.append(['complete_name', operator, name]) this statement.
And you have to follow above stated syntax.

Comment: Hello, or I have to change my def name_search, yes? How can I change it to new api with self environment and recorset?